# how to resolve the java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in maven

Tags: java, rest, maven

the my web-app working fine in eclipse and the Netbeas but when i try to execute in maven after include the dependency its throwing exception.The dependency is.

```
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
       <version>2.1.2</version>
     </dependency>
```

This dependency i include because i am using the
ResponseBuilderImpl builder = new ResponseBuilderImpl()
if i remove the builder and dependency  then its work in maven but when i included then its giving exception.this is my rest sample rest code.

```
       @Path("/{userId}/logout")
   @PUT
   public Response logout(@PathParam ("userId") String userId,@Context HttpServletRequest request,@Context HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException 
   {
    ResponseBuilderImpl builder = new ResponseBuilderImpl();
    log.debug("request user id for logout::"+userId);
    MapUserLogin mapUserLogin=new MapUserLogin();
    mapUserLogin.removeMap(userId);
    log.debug("after remove userinformation from hashmap");

    System.out.print("LOGOUT SUCCESSFULLUY");
    builder.status(200).entity("SUCCESS");
    return builder.build();

   }
```

so for the ResponseBuilderImpl i imported the import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseBuilderImpl
if i remove and just return string types then its work but when i am using this above code then only maven is throwing exception The exception is.

```
INFO: Deployed Application(path=C:\App\apache-tomee-jaxrs-1.5.2\webapps\Snefocaremaven)
Oct 01, 2013 10:51:10 AM org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager fireEvent
SEVERE: error invoking org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager$Observer@21d4f61d
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: full stack trace here link:
http://www.docdroid.net/4pce/cataline.txt.html


This exception is only coming when i used the ResponseBuilderImpl in my rest services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a good reason to use the CXF-specific `ResponseBuilderImpl` you should use the static factory methods of the JAX-RS `Response` class to obtain a ResponseBuilder, e.g.

```
Response response = Response.status(200).entity("SUCCESS").build();
```

The JAX-RS framework will use an internal mechanism to load and initialize the correct implementation. Note that you should not need the CXF dependency at compile time, unless you are using proprietary features.

**update**:

```
ResponseBuilder partial = Response.status(200);
```

Will create a mutable builder instance, which can be further modified. Note that you should also be able to modify the status on the builder. Unfortunately (?) there is no "plain" factory method available from the JAX-RS API. I would suggest to first try out the creation of a `Response` this way and check, whether it works or if there are more subtle problems.

```
ResponseBuilder partial = Response.status(200); // mock status
ResponseBuilder filled = fillResponse(partial); // whatever the method is called
return filled.build();
```

Then you can think about refactoring to get rid of the creation of the builder with a mock status, for example by moving the whole response building into a method that knows the entity and response code.

Comment: here i gave just sample code but after creating response object i need to pass to other method .and there entity and the status is store in response object so for that i crating responsebuilderimpl object and pass to method and then from builder i am creating the response object and send back to client.

Comment: i cant create the response object what you say.as i have to pass response object to other method.so for that i used this ResponseBUilderImpl

Comment: Using the JAX-RS API must work, so there is a problem with your servlet container configuration. Does the exception occur when you start up the tomcat instance or when you actually send a request to the service? Maybe you are missing runtime dependencies, you should check back with the openejb documentation / make sure you have the latest version of tomEE.

Comment: thanks. its working fine in eclipse as well as in maven..but my question is the why eclipse is supporting but not the maven.

Comment: I suspect that there is a missing dependency in the maven build, that is present when you execute the project from within eclipse.

Comment: no .i included that dependency .and this is occurs at run time.